# Modal Enzyme mount unit test: MutationObserver is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to make a unit test for a react modal:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import Modal from ".";
import "wicg-inert";
import "animate.css";

describe("Modal component", () => {
  describe("When props is missing", () => {
    it("should raise an exception", () => {
      expect(() => mount(<Modal />)).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

It Fails with this message:
Test suite failed to run

```
ReferenceError: MutationObserver is not defined

  4 | import classnames from "classnames";
  5 | import Button, { ButtonGroup } from "components/Button";
> 6 | import "wicg-inert";
  7 | import "animate.css";
  8 |
  9 | import "./Modal.scss";

  at new InertManager (node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:537:28)
  at node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:792:22
  at node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:2:66
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/wicg-inert/dist/inert.js:5:2)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Modal/Modal.jsx:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Modal/index.mjs:1:318)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Modal/Modal.test.js:3:32)
```

My impression is that is failing because of limitation with Enzyme simulating the DOM. Can it be solved with react-test-library? Or with Enzyme itself?